# Org-mode, LaTeX, PDF & centering side by side images

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment, org-mode

I need to solve a recent problem placing images side by side in the center of a PDF that is generated by *org-mode* via LaTeX.

I recently opened some `.org`-files from a year ago and tried to generate new PDFs from them. There have been significant updates to emacs, org-mode, and the relevant LaTeX packages I use, so some parts of the source had to be changed. Mostly, everything is working now except for generating PDFs with **centered, side by side images**.

Here is what used to work:

```
#+BEGIN_center
#+ATTR_LaTeX: :height 0.2\textwidth
[[image1.png]]
#+ATTR_LaTeX: :height 0.2\textwidth
[[image2.png]]
#+END_center
```

I am currently using emacs 26.0.50, orgmode 9.0.3, with TeX Live 2016 on Debian and the example above results in images that are stacked on top of each other. When I examine the TeX source, this is the result:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[height=0.2\textwidth]{image1.png}
\end{center}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[height=0.2\textwidth]{image2.png}
\end{center}
\end{center}
```

I assume this is related to recent change in org-mode where images are centered by default. However, the following change to the org source does not solve the problem.

```
#+ATTR_LaTeX: :height 0.2\textwidth
[[image1.png]]
#+ATTR_LaTeX: :height 0.2\textwidth
[[image2.png]]
```

The images are still stacked on top of each other (although the outer "\center" calls are no longer present in resulting tex source):

```
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[height=0.2\textwidth]{image1.png}
\end{center}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[height=0.2\textwidth]{image2.png}
\end{center}
```

I am able to get the images side by side if I disable org-mode's automatic centering:

```
#+ATTR_LaTeX: :height 0.2\textwidth :center
[[image1.png]]
#+ATTR_LaTeX: :height 0.2\textwidth :center
[[image2.png]]
```

But how can I get side by side images centered? Perhaps the answer is very  simple and obvious, but I have tried many other changes and been unable to accomplish this.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

After trying a few more things, I managed to solve it myself:

```
#+BEGIN_center
#+ATTR_LaTeX: :height 0.2\textwidth :center
[[image1.png]]
#+ATTR_LaTeX: :height 0.2\textwidth :center
[[image2.png]]
#+END_center
```

Leave the `#+ _center` keywords that surround the images to be centered, but then disable org-mode's new automatic centering by adding `:center` for each image. This also means there is no need to remove existing markup.

Resulting LaTex output looks as it should:

```
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[height=0.2\textwidth]{image1.png}
\includegraphics[height=0.2\textwidth]{image2.png}
\end{center}
```

If anyone has a simpler or more elegant solution than adding `:center` to each instance, please post. Until then, the solution above at least works.

Comment: +1 (but it would be even better if you posted the resulting LaTeX output).

Comment: @jon Updated answer to include it

Comment: How about using this with captions?